# How do you transform several numerical columns of a data frame into categories at once?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I have a `df` dataframe with numbers between 1 and 7 and I would like to transform them into catagories (`neg` if <3, `pos` if >5 and `neut` if not):

```
    A       B       C       D       E
0   3.75    3.50    4.00    4.75    3.00
1   4.75    5.25    3.75    5.50    2.00
2   3.25    4.00    3.75    4.00    5.50
3   2.75    4.00    4.00    4.00    2.75
```

So I tried:

```
for col in columns:
    for _, row in df[col].iterrows():
        if row<3:
            df.iloc[i,row] = "neg"
        elif row >5:
            df.iloc[i,row] = "pos"
        else:
            df.iloc[i,row] = "neut"
```

But got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-71393cdf0d1e> in <module>
      2 
      3 for col in columns:
----> 4     for _, row in df[col].iterrows():
      5         if row<3:
      6             df.iloc[i,row] = "neg"

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

I also tried:

```
df.loc[df['A','B', 'C', 'D','E'] > 5, ['A','B', 'C', 'D','E']] = "pos"
```

But it returned:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: ('Openess', 'Conscientiousness', 'Extraversion', 'Agreeableness', 'Neuroticism')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-bd0104cc9380> in <module>
     11 #             df.iloc[i,row] = "neut"
     12 
---> 13 df.loc[df['Openess','Conscientiousness', 'Extraversion', 'Agreeableness','Neuroticism'] > 5, ['Openess','Conscientiousness', 'Extraversion', 'Agreeableness','Neuroticism']] = "pos"

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: ('Openess', 'Conscientiousness', 'Extraversion', 'Agreeableness', 'Neuroticism')
```